# Product rule for multi-dimensional Ito processes

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we have d-dimensional Ito process $X_t$ with:

$dX_t = b(t, X_t)dt + \sigma(t, X_t)dW_t$,

where $W_t$ is d-dimensional standard Brownian motion.

And one-dimensional Ito process $Y_t = f(X_t)$:

$dY_t = [\partial_t f + \nabla_x f^T b + 1/2 \text{Tr}(\sigma \text{Hess}_x f \sigma)]dt + \nabla_x f \sigma dW_t,$

where $f(x) : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $Y_t$ is derived by Ito's formula.

Is it true that $Y_t X_t$ is still d-dimensional Ito process, that is,

$Y_tX_t = Y_0X_0 + \int_0^t X_sdY_s + \int_0^t Y_sdX_s + \int_0^t dX_sdY_s?$

And if it is true, can I get the Fokker-Planck equation from this?

(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Yes, and $…+∇xf^Tσ\,dW_t$. You could also directly start with $g(x)=f(x)x$. You should perhaps explicitly mention if $W_t$ is one-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!